# How to export c file/function to FMU using fmusdk

Tags: c, fmi

This is my function. I am trying to export this code to [fmu](http://fmi-standard.org/downloads/). I am using [fmusdk](https://github.com/cxbrooks/fmusdk2).

For each cycle(time step),

1. my `input` should be changed to the value given during simulation.
2. `myexecute()` should be called.
3. the values of `input` and `pout` should be stored during simulation, so that we can plot the values after the simulation.

I tried the examples(BouncingBall and values) given in [fmusdk](https://github.com/cxbrooks/fmusdk2). I have created corresponding fmus and imported them in Amesim. They are working fine.  But i am unable to figure out how to do the same for my C file/function

```
/*
 * Execution function
 */
void  myexecute(double *input, double *pout) 
{
  (*pout) = 2 * (*input);
}
```

I examined the bouncingBall.c and values.c, they have only four methods

```
setStartValues(ModelInstance *comp)
calculateValues(ModelInstance *comp)
getReal(ModelInstance *comp, fmi2ValueReference vr)
void eventUpdate(ModelInstance *comp, fmi2EventInfo *eventInfo, int isTimeEvent, int isNewEventIteration)
```

Can someone help me in accomplishing this fmi export? In short i am looking for the contents for the above 4 functions. Explaination for the above 4 methods will also be sufficient. I can create the contents for the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the C file given below similar to the files you mentioned  bouncingBall.c or valus.c . Since you have referred the function `myexecute` from another c file, replace `yourCFile.c` and/or `yourHFile.h` with the correct files.
Also your modelDescription.xml should be in sync with this C file. For ex) `guid` value should be the same in both files. Also the value reference for the scalar variables should be the same. Analyse `<ScalarVariable name="pin" valueReference="0">` and `#define pin_  0` . Similarly for `pout`. Create a folder structure similar to bouncingBall. Create a separate batch file, since we have to include additional files(`yourCFile.c` and/or `yourHFile.h`)

```
// define class name and unique id
#define MODEL_IDENTIFIER modelName
#define MODEL_GUID "{8c4e810f-3df3-4a00-8276-176fa3c90123}"

// define model size
#define NUMBER_OF_REALS 2
#define NUMBER_OF_INTEGERS 0
#define NUMBER_OF_BOOLEANS 0
#define NUMBER_OF_STRINGS 0
#define NUMBER_OF_STATES 1
#define NUMBER_OF_EVENT_INDICATORS 0

// include fmu header files, typedefs and macros
#include "fmuTemplate.h"
#include "yourHFile.h"
#include "yourCFile.c"

// define all model variables and their value references
// conventions used here:
// - if x is a variable, then macro x_ is its variable reference
// - the vr of a variable is its index in array  r, i, b or s
// - if k is the vr of a real state, then k+1 is the vr of its derivative
#define pin_        0
#define pout_       1

// define state vector as vector of value references
#define STATES { pout_ }

// called by fmi2Instantiate
// Set values for all variables that define a start value
// Settings used unless changed by fmi2SetX before fmi2EnterInitializationMode
void setStartValues(ModelInstance *comp) {
    r(pin_) = 2;
    r(pout_) = 4;
}

// called by fmi2GetReal, fmi2GetInteger, fmi2GetBoolean, fmi2GetString, fmi2ExitInitialization
// if setStartValues or environment set new values through fmi2SetXXX.
// Lazy set values for all variable that are computed from other variables.
void calculateValues(ModelInstance *comp) {
    if (comp->state == modelInitializationMode) {
        // set first time event
        comp->eventInfo.nextEventTimeDefined = fmi2True;
    }
}

// called by fmi2GetReal, fmi2GetContinuousStates and fmi2GetDerivatives
fmi2Real getReal(ModelInstance *comp, fmi2ValueReference vr){
    switch (vr) {
        case pin_  : return  r(pin_);
        case pout_ : return     r(pout_);
        default: return 0;
    }
}

// used to set the next time event, if any.
void eventUpdate(ModelInstance *comp, fmi2EventInfo *eventInfo, int isTimeEvent, int isNewEventIteration) {
    myexecute(&r(pin_), &r(pout_));
}

#include "fmuTemplate.c"
```